# Unknown column 'x' in 'where clause'

Tags: mysql, delphi

I'm using MySql , Delphi.
What's my wrong at below code ??

I get "Unknown Column 'x' in where clause"
Error -->  Unknown column '_code_ehda_konandeh' in 'where clause'
I so need it.
i have to do this proj for 2 days later
please........

---

```
   DELIMITER $$

USE `bimarestan`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `Save_Ehda_Konande`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `Save_Ehda_Konande`(
IN _code_ehda_konandeh VARCHAR(50),
IN _tarikh_moarefi VARCHAR(50),
IN _tarikh_tashkil_parvandeh VARCHAR(50),
IN _name VARCHAR(50),
IN _name_khanevadegi VARCHAR(50),
IN _name_pedar VARCHAR(50),
IN _tarikh_tavalod VARCHAR(20),
IN _tahsilat VARCHAR(50),
IN _vaziyat_taahol VARCHAR(50),
IN _noe_bimeh VARCHAR(50),
IN _gorooh_khoon VARCHAR(50),
IN _rezayat_dahandeh VARCHAR(50),
IN _shoghl VARCHAR(50),
IN _address VARCHAR(50),
IN _telphone VARCHAR(50),
OUT _out INT)
BEGIN
IF LTRIM(RTRIM(_code_ehda_konandeh))<>'' THEN
 BEGIN
 SET _out = 0;
  IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM bimar WHERE `_code_ehda_konandeh` = `code_ehda_konandeh`) THEN
    INSERT INTO `ehda_konandeh` (
code_ehda_konandeh,
tarikh_moarefi,
tarikh_tashkil_parvandeh,
NAME,
name_khanevadegi,
name_pedar,
tarikh_tavalod,
tahsilat,
vaziyat_taahol,
noe_bimeh,
gorooh_khoon,
rezayat_dahandeh,
shoghl,
address,
telphone)
    VALUES(
_code_ehda_konandeh,
_tarikh_moarefi,
_tarikh_tashkil_parvandeh,
_name,
_name_khanevadegi,
_name_pedar,
_tarikh_tavalod,
_tahsilat,
_vaziyat_taahol,
_noe_bimeh,
_gorooh_khoon,
_rezayat_dahandeh,
_shoghl,
_address,
_telphone
);
  ELSE
    SET _out = 1;  
  END IF;
    END; 
END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

---

that Stored Proc Run at MySql Without any problems but when i want send delphi parameters to that, i get that error!!

and this is my delphi code :

```
if flag_new_edit = 1 then
  sp_sabt.StoredProcName := 'Save_Ehda_Konande'
 else
  sp_sabt.StoredProcName := 'Edit_Ehda_Konande';
   With sp_sabt Do
   Begin
   ParamByName('_code_ehda_konandeh').Value := Trim(txt_code_ehda_konande.Text);
   ParamByName('_tarikh_moarefi').Value := Trim(txt_tarikh_tavalod.Text);
   ParamByName('_tarikh_tashkil_parvandeh').Value := Trim(txt_name_khanevadegi.Text);
   ParamByName('_name').Value := Trim(txt_name.Text);
   ParamByName('_name_khanevadegi').Value := Trim(txt_name_khanevadegi.Text);
   ParamByName('_name_pedar').Value := Trim(txt_name_pedar.Text);
   ParamByName('_tarikh_tavalod').Value := Trim(txt_tarikh_tavalod.Text);
   ParamByName('_tahsilat').Value := Trim(cmb_tahsilat.Text);
   ParamByName('_vaziyat_taahol').Value := Trim(cmb_vaziyat_taahol.Text);
   ParamByName('_noe_bimeh').Value := Trim(cmb_noe_bime.Text);
   ParamByName('_gorooh_khoon').Value := Trim(cmb_gorooh_khoon.Text);
   ParamByName('_rezayat_dahandeh').Value := Trim(txt_rezayat_dahande.Text);
   ParamByName('_shoghl').Value := Trim(txt_shoghl.Text);
   ParamByName('_address').Value := Trim(txt_adress.Text);
   ParamByName('_telphone').Value := Trim(txt_tel.Text);
   ExecProc;
End;
```

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though I pointed out what the error could be in your sql code, I would like to give more details on it.

*`That Stored Procedure Runing at MySql WithOut any problems but when send Delphi parameters to sp , i get that Error !!`* But you are wrong.

There is [***`a known bug`***](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=26394) in your procedure creation. Due to the reason a *runtime exception was raised*.
*`Semantics of Stored procedure code is not checked at CREATE time. At runtime, undeclared variables are detected, and an error message is generated for each reference to an undeclared variable. However, SP's seem to believe any reference denotes a column, even though the syntactic context excludes that. This leads to a very confusing error message in case the procedure.`*

A standard test example is as shown below:

```
mysql> drop procedure proc_test;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> delimiter //
mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE proc_test()
    -> BEGIN
    ->     select current_day;
    -> END
    -> //
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Here you can understand that procedure compilation ignored on what `current day` is.

```
mysql> delimiter ;
mysql> call proc_test();
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'current_day' in 'field list'
mysql>
```

With this you should understand that *`That Stored Procedure Runing at MySql WithOut any problems ...`* is not correct.

---

A quick fix to your query will resolve the issue. You mentioned that *`I defined input parameters with _ prefix. I don't know waht i must do !`*. If that is true, then
change

```
SELECT * FROM bimar WHERE `_code_ehda_konandeh` = `code_ehda_konandeh`
```

to

```
SELECT * FROM bimar WHERE `code_ehda_konandeh` = _code_ehda_konandeh
```

and it should be working. Here I assumed `code_ehda_konandeh` is a column of table `bimar` too.

Answer (score 3):

```
  IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM bimar WHERE `_code_ehda_konandeh` = `code_ehda_konandeh`) THEN
                                          ^---                ^---
```

remove the indicated quotes. backticks are used to "escape" reserved words. They also force MySQL to treat those escaped words as field/table names. Your parameters are not fields, so MySQL's being forced to misinterpret them as such.

Comment: That Stored Procedure Runing at MySql WithOut any problems but when send Delphi parameters to sp , i get that Error !!

Comment: @hamedkamrava - Definitely it should be the error. `_code_ehda_konandeh` must be input parameter to the procedure and `code_ehda_konandeh`, *without underscore as prefix*, is the column name. I do have a doubt on error stack trace. Show us results of `desc bimar`.

Comment: @Ravinder - I defined input parameters with _ prefix. I don't know waht i must do !

Comment: @hamedkamrava - Then referring *`\`code_ehda_konandeh\``* must be wrong. Does `bimar` have both `code_ehda_konandeh`, `_code_ehda_konandeh` fields? Your query says, `code_ehda_konandeh` is a field of `ehda_konandeh` table but not `bimar`. Then how could you use it in `where` clause without referring its table name?

Comment: @Ravinder - Thank You.You'r right i was fool :) tnx so much dude