# In MySql Stored Procedure updating more than one time

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

**In MySql**

```
UPDATE `inventoryentry` SET `Status` = 1 WHERE `InventoryID`=92 AND `ItemID`=28;
```

It successfully update only one row , where inventoryID = 92 and itemID=28 , the following message displayed.

```
1 row(s) affected
```

when I put this on stored procedure, as follow

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `Sample`(IN itemId INT, IN itemQnty 
DOUBLE, IN invID INT)

BEGIN

DECLARE crntQnty DOUBLE;
DECLARE nwQnty DOUBLE;

SET crntQnty=(SELECT `QuantityOnHand` FROM `item` WHERE id=itemId);
SET nwQnty=itemQnty+crntQnty;
UPDATE `item` SET `QuantityOnHand`=nwQnty WHERE `Id`=itemId;

UPDATE `inventoryentry` SET `Status` = 1 WHERE `InventoryID`=invID AND 
`ItemID`=itemId;


END$$
```

**calling stored procedures**

```
CALL Sample(28,10,92)
```

It update all the status = 1 in **inventoryentry** against **InventoryID** (i.e. 92) ignoring ItemID, instead of updating only one row. The following message displayed!

```
5 row(s) affected
```

Why Stored procedure ignoring itemID in update statement ? or Why Stored procedure updating more than one time? But without Stored procedure it working fine.

Comment: Check whether you have executed latest sp script on server.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use different variable names apart from your field name, also use the table name with the columns for better understanding like i used in following:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `Sample`(IN itemID INT, IN itemQnty 
DOUBLE, IN invID INT)

BEGIN

DECLARE crntQnty DOUBLE;
DECLARE nwQnty DOUBLE;

SET crntQnty=(SELECT `QuantityOnHand` FROM `item` WHERE id=itemID);
SET nwQnty=itemQnty+crntQnty;
UPDATE `item` SET `QuantityOnHand`=nwQnty WHERE `QuantityOnHand`.`Id`=itemID;

UPDATE `inventoryentry` SET `Status` = 1 WHERE `InventoryID`=invID AND 
`inventoryentry`.`ItemID`=itemID;


END$$
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10832827/execute-second-update-if-first-update-execute-successfully

Answer (score 2):

because of

```
update inventoryentry ... WHERE ... AND `ItemID`=itemId
```

You are saying that column `itemid` should be the same as column `itemid` which is always `true`

Try renaming your parameter to a name that differs from your column name

Answer (score 1):

*[Using same names for columns and variable names has some issues](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=26394)*.

> Semantics of Stored procedure code is not checked at CREATE time. At runtime, undeclared variables are detected, and an error message is generated for each reference to an undeclared variable. However, SP's seem to believe any reference denotes a column, even though the syntactic context excludes that. This leads to a very confusing error message in case the procedure.

Your column name `ItemID` matches with input variable name `itemId`, and hence is the issue.

Please look at my answer to a similar query ***[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673766/unknown-column-x-in-where-clause/10688275#10688275)***.