# Execute second update if first update execute successfully

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

**Stored Procedure**

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `Sample`(IN itemId INT, IN itemQnty 
DOUBLE, IN invID INT)

BEGIN

DECLARE crntQnty DOUBLE;
DECLARE nwQnty DOUBLE;

SET crntQnty=(SELECT `QuantityOnHand` FROM `item` WHERE id=itemId);
SET nwQnty=itemQnty+crntQnty;
UPDATE `item` SET `QuantityOnHand`=nwQnty WHERE `Id`=itemId;

UPDATE `inventoryentry` SET `Status` = 1 WHERE `InventoryID`=invID AND 
`ItemID`=itemId;


END$$
```

In this stored procedure I have two update statements. IF first update execute successfully then second execute. what changes required to be made?

Comment: what do you mean on "execute successfully" - without errors or `QuantityOnHand` takes new value?

Comment: When execute without errors, its means that QuantityOnHand taken new value. Ultimately my focus on QuantityOnHand. @triclosan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the first `UPDATE` you can check the number of rows that were affected by `ROW_COUNT()`.

If the `ROW_COUNT()` returns the desired number of updates you want (maybe > 0) then only  fire second `UPDATE`.

Yo can surround the second `UPDATE` by an `IF - END IF` checking for the number of rows that were affected.

Comment: Immediately after the first `UPDATE ... ;` write `IF ROW_COUNT() > 0 THEN`   `UPDATE ... END IF;`

Answer (score 0):

Use `SELECT ROW_COUNT();` to determine if any rows were affected.  If the count is greater than zero, or equal to the number of rows expected, then the update was successful.