# Execute SQL Query if other is successful

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query

```
INSERT INTO balance
(_id, value)
VALUES
(1,10) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY 
UPDATE value=VALUES(value + 10)
```

Obviously this updates a row, and if the row doesn't exist, it creates that row.

Now I want to execute the following query after the previous one has completed successfully

```
INSERT INTO transaction (owner, value, type, description) VALUES (1, 10,'CREDIT','User Deposit');
```

How can I chain the two queries where the second is only executed if the first is successful.

Any ideas?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10832827/execute-second-update-if-first-update-execute-successfully

Comment: The question is labeled mysql but has syntax from sql-server. Could you fix the labels or clarify that you are indeed on mysql?

Comment: "How can I chain the two queries where the second is only executed if the first is successful. " Not possible with plain SQL in MySQL because UPDATE and INSERT are separated processes.. best method is to use a after update trigger on table balance which will insert

Comment: Is this homework? That poorly named table reeks of textbook clues. But it seems as though you really want to do the second INSERT based on a join with the balance table.. that is, add a row to the transaction table by looking up the values you'll need from the balance table, keyed on the id. That way, if no balance record exists for this _id, no transaction row will be inserted.

And you want to wrap the whole thing in BEGIN TRAN / COMMIT.

Comment: @SQLCliff Not homework no. What would you recommend calling the tables?

Comment: Didn't mean to come off rude. Transaction is a reserved word... you can name a table that, but it might make code confusing. transAudit? transLog?

Comment: @SQLCliff I thought that may be what you was talking about. Yes makes sense to rename it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use the output clause:

```
UPDATE TableA
SET ColA = 'SomethingNew'
OUTPUT DELETED.ColA , INSERTED.ColA 
WHERE YourLogicHere;
GO;
```

Comment: MySQL doesn't support OUTPUT clause.. OUTPUT is SQL-server syntax.

Comment: @RaymondNijland That is true and the question is labeled 'mysql' however the OP is using @@RowCount which is SQL-Server syntax

Comment: @DanielGale Yep only realised that just now. I hadn't even attempted to execute the query until I had figured out the rest. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the InnoDB engine, you should just use a transaction:

```
START TRANSACTION;

INSERT INTO balance
(_id, value)
VALUES
(1,10) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY 
UPDATE value=VALUES(value + 10);

INSERT INTO transaction (owner, value, type, description) VALUES (1, 10,'CREDIT','User Deposit');

COMMIT;
```

If the first statement fails, the second won't be commited.

Answer (score 0):

Use row count.Sorry for typos using mobile
INSERT INTO balance
(_id, value)
VALUES
(1,10) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY 
UPDATE value=VALUES(value + 10)

Select row_count into @count; 
If @count>0 then 
INSERT INTO transaction (owner, value, type, description) VALUES (1, 10,'CREDIT','User Deposit');

End if;